# Bubble sort in Python

Tags: python, beginner, sorting

I am quite new in Python and I am starting my journey with sorting algorithms, PEP8 and the Zen of Python. I would like to get some feedback about my BubbleSort algorithm which I wrote.
Also, is there a possibility to change the `break` statement to something else which will stop the loop?

```
def bubble_sort(structure):
    """
        Bubble sort.

        Description
        ----------
        Performance cases:
        Worst      : O(n^2)
        Average    : O(n^2)
        Best case  : O(n)

        Parameters
        ----------
        structure : Mutable structure with comparable objects.

        Returns
        -------
        structure : return sorted structure.

        Examples
        ----------
        >>> bubble_sort([7,1,2,6,4,2,3])
        [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]

        >>> bubble_sort(['a', 'c', 'b'])
        ['a', 'b', 'c']

    """

    length = len(structure)

    while True:
        changed = False
        for i in range(length - 1):
            if structure[i] > structure[i + 1]:
                structure[i], structure[i + 1] = structure[i + 1], structure[i]
                changed = True
        if not changed:
            break
    return structure
```

Comment: You can implement it with 2 for loops, then you can get rid of the `break`

Comment: I get an idea now what if i change the `break` statment to `return structure` and delete the last line `return structure`. Will it harmonize with PEP8?

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks nice and the documentation is high quality.

Maybe a few things can be improved anyway.

**API**

It could be a good idea to get inspiration from the Python API functions related to sorting, we have:

- [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) returning a new list from an iterable
- [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) sorts a list in place, returns None

In your case, as `structure` is sorted in place, I am not sure it makes sense to return it.

**Parameter `structure`**

This is mostly personal opinion but instead of `structure`, I'd find `container` to be a better name.

Also, if you want to be precise in the documentation, you might want to say that it is `mutable` but also that it implements `__len__`, `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`. These objects are also called [(mutable) sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types).

**The code**

Not much to say about the code itself.

Instead of having `if not changed: break`, you could write a: `while changed` loop which is very slightly more concise.

Also, you'll find an optimisation suggestion on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort):

> The bubble sort algorithm can be easily optimized by observing that the n-th pass finds the n-th largest element and puts it into its final place. So, the inner loop can avoid looking at the last n − 1 items when running for the n-th time

Before getting into such a change, I highly recommend writing unit tests.

Comment: I have one more question. How can i make a copy of the `structure` to return it as `sorted` does ?

Comment: Changing the struct in place is fine to me. However, if you need, you could use the copy module. Alternatively, you could just also just call list to copy your container as a list.